How to Create a Top Toggle Button Like Google App in Flutter with Material 3?
similar to the one seen in the Google app’s homepage using Flutter and Material 3. The button in the Google app is positioned at the top of the screen and toggles between different views or sections. I would like to achieve a similar effect in my Flutter app.
Google app home page
Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to create a top toggle button with smooth animations and Material 3 styling in Flutter? Any help or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!
